# Converting CSS into SCSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite this CSS code in SCSS. Our teacher was showing us how SCSS makes your code easier to read, but I'm currently having a lot of trouble just writing it to fit that format.

I tried to rewrite the code and failed miserably. I just need help writing this code into SCSS. I don't understand what code can be nested and simplified and what code is fine.

```
   * {
        margin:0; /* its better to use a reset like normalize.css */
        padding:0;
        box-sizing:border-box; /* this will make padding andborder included 
       iin widths- this is best for responsive layouts*/
        }

     body {
        font-family:sans-serif;/* sets default font for entire site*/
        background-image: url(../images/object.gif);
        overflow-y: scroll;

        }


    img {
        max-width:100%;
        display:block;
        }

    /* these are some commonly used style you can add as defaults*/
        .bold {font-weight:bold;}
        .italics {font-style: italic;}

        .clearfix {clear:both;} /*used to clear floats */

        a:link {color:white;}
        a:visited {color:white;}
        a:hover {color:yellow;}
        a:active {color:violet;}

    header {
        background-color:gray;
        margin:1px;
        padding:1em;
        border:1px solid white;
        border-radius:2px 2px 3px;
        }

    h2 {
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        }

    h3 {
        color:white;
        text-align:left;
        padding:1em;
        font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
        }

    nav ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        padding:1em;
    }

    nav ul li {
        flex-grow:1;
    }

    nav li a {
        display:block; 
        text-align:center;
        margin:1em;
        }

    &nav li a:hover {
        background-color:gray;
    }

    p {
        color:white;
        }

    main {
        background-color:black;
        padding: 1em;

        }

    section {
        background-image: url(images/silver.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        }

    .colum {
        width:100%;
        margin-top:1em;
        }

    .logo {
        width:50%;
    }

    .box {
        width:100%;
        padding-top:2em;
        }

    .grid-item {
        padding-top:1em;
        padding-bottom:4%;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100%;
        transition-property:color, font-size;
            transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in;
        }

    .grid-item:hover {
        color:white;
        }

    form {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        background-color:black;
        max-width:100%;
        font-family:helvetica;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:1em;
        }

    label {
        background-color:white;
        padding: 1em;
        display:block;
        }

    input, select {
        background-color:lightgray;
        margin:1em 0;
        width:100%;
        padding:1em;
        }

        .box {
            max-width:700px;
        }

    textarea {
        width:100%;
        padding:1em;
        margin:1em 0;
        margin-top:1em;
        }

    .name-field {
        width:100%;
        }

    button {
        padding-top:1em;
        padding: 1em;
        font-size:1.5em;
        background-color:white;
        }

    .text {
        font-size:12px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top:2em;
        }

    footer {
        background-color:black;
        padding:1em;
        margin:1px;
        border:1px solid white;
        border-radius:2px 2px 3px;
        }

/* ================ Mobile First Method media queries ============= */

/* small devices and tablets */ 
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    #wrap {
        width:90%;
        max-width:1200px;
        margin:0 auto;
        }

    .row {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        padding-left:1em;
        padding-bottom:1em;

        }

    .colum {
        flex-grow:1;
        flex-basis:50%;
        padding:1em;
        padding-left:1em;
        padding-bottom:1em;
        width:100%;
        }

    .box {
        max-width:700px;
        padding-left:1em;
        padding-bottom:1em;
        }

    .grid-item {
        width:40%;
    }

    .grid-sizer {
        width:40%;
    }

    .gutter-sizer {
        width:5%;
    }

    form {
        width:50%;
        }

    .logo {
        width:100%;
    }

/* medium devices, desk tops */
@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {

    nav ul {
        flex-direction:row; 
        justify-content:space-between; 
        }

    nav ul li {
        flex-grow:1;
        }

    .grid-item {
        width:30%;
    }

    .grid-sizer {
        width:30%;
    }
}

  /* Large devices, wide screens */
  @media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {

    .grid-item {
        width:30%;
    }

    .grid-sizer {
        width:30%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did. this is not homework site where you give us work

Comment: You may get more help at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If this is supposed to be the raw CSS, there is not much you can gain by nesting selectors, because the majority of the selectors here are completely independent of each other. You could write `& li` instead of `nav ul li`, but that's about it.

Comment: only the `nav ul` parts can be refactored to SCSS, the rest is already optimal. If your question is how to do it, then you should read tutorials, it's extremely simple. then, after you've read and tried, come back and ask.